# Differentiation: what rule am I missing here?

Tags: derivatives

I am trying to differentiate the below with respect to c:
$\left(\frac{a-b}{c-b}\right)^d$, however I get an answer different to what Mathematica (and other sources) is telling me, which is
$-\frac{(a-b)\left(\frac{a-b}{c-b}\right)^{d-1}d}{(c-b)^2}$

The way I'm approaching it is:
$\left(\frac{a-b}{c-b}\right)^d = \frac{(a-b)^d}{(c-b)^d} = (a-b)^d*(c-b)^{-d}$,
then I treat $(a-b)^d$ as a constant and differentiate the $(c-b)^{-d}$ term which gives me:
$(a-b)^d * -d(c-b)^{-d-1} = \frac{-d(a-b)^d}{(c-b)^{d-1}}$.

I can't work out what rule or a method I'm missing here unfortunately so I would be very grateful for any advice or pointers on that.
Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is in the last transformation of you work:

$$(c-b)^{-d-1} = \frac1{{(c-b)}^{d\color{red}+1}}$$

Taking this correction into account, you'll see that then your and Mathematica's answer are actually the same.